# Cannot change the css visibilty of <DIV> by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am struggling with a bit of Javascript which is a real mystery for me, because it works perfectly on another project, and the solutions on google matches my code.

I start with some *div*s, some are hidden, some are visible (with CSS) and the visibility should change when the `start()` function (Javascript) is called. But it won't. Other CSS properties can be changed perfectly and I just cannot find the mistake.

HTML/CSS:

```
<style>
    .div1 {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    ...
</style>
```

In the body:

```
<div class="div1" id="div1">
    ...
</div>
<div class="div2" id="div2">
    ...
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function start() { // Is called by a push of a "Start" button
    tmrTestStart = new Date().getTime(); 
    fillRandomNumbers();

    document.getElementById("div1").style.visibilty = "visible";
    document.getElementById("div2").style.visibilty = "hidden";

    document.getElementById("div2").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000"; // works perfectly
}
```

Comment: Possible syntax error: `.style.visibilty` should be `.style.visibility`

Comment: are you **100%** sure that function actually fires?

Comment: Yes, it was the spelling mistake :D embarrassing.

Answer (score 1):

visibility not visibilty

```
document.getElementById("div2").style.visibility = "hidden" ;
```

Comment: Wow, that's why you shouldn't copy & paste your own code D:

Answer (score 0):

It has to be ".style.visibility", not ".style.visibilty"

Answer (score 0):

Simple syntax mistake :

```
document.getElementById("div1").style.visibilty = "visible";
```

should be :

```
document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility = "visible";
```

Demonstration : https://codepen.io/andreds/pen/dJVXPW

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "none";
```